# Require at least one entry to be completed in a repeating section

Tags: cognito-forms

How can I set up a web form using Cognito Forms such that users can only submit it if they have completed at least one entry in a repeating section?

I have tried setting "require > always" for the subsections of each entry (there is no similar option for the complete repeating section)  but users can still submit the form if they delete all entries.

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

This is an idea that has been brought to our attention and a feature that we do plan to add in the future, you can follow the progress for this over on our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/PjL6svlg).

Comment: While this is not a perfect solution, you can also add a Calculation field of type Number to your form, with a calculation like `=RepeatingSection.Count()` and specify 1 as the Min for the Range.  This will prevent the form from being submitted if all of the repeating sections are removed.